# Writing data over Influx HTTP API returns OK, but table is empty

Tags: influxdb

I'm writing batched data over HTTP API like this

> demo,state=idle
>   max=100.0,mean=20.0,event_type=0,probability=0.6,min=0.0 1529087114083
>   demo,state=idle
>   max=100.0,mean=80.0,event_type=1,probability=0.6,min=0.0 1529087114083
>   demo,state=idle
>   max=100.0,mean=20.0,event_type=2,probability=0.6,min=0.0 1529087114083
>   demo,state=idle
>   max=100.0,mean=80.0,event_type=3,probability=0.6,min=0.0 1529087114083

And the request returns 204 which is "ok" according to Influx API docs. 
Still, when I want to check my data in admin

> SELECT median("mean") AS "median_mean", mean("mean") AS "mean_mean"
>   FROM "sfb"."autogen"."demo" WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY
>   :interval: FILL(null)

I get

> Your query is syntactically correct but returned no results

Answer (score 2):

Solved: need to specify proper timestamp precision - otherwise it calculates wrong data and data is not visible